# Convert string "2/10/2014 10:12:12 AM" to same format in NSDate in obj c?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have string `@"2/10/2014 10:12:12 AM"` (month/day/year hour:minute:second am/pm) in this format. How to convert it into NSDate format.
I feel it easy but not getting in same format.

Comment: try DD/MM/YY hh:mm:ss a

Comment: Please check edited question.I try this but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

NSString *dateString = @"12/24/2014 10:32:42 PM";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Next thing you'll need to figure out is the time zones.

Comment: I am getting this 2014-12-24 17:02:42 +0000 not which i want. I want back it again like @"12/24/2014 10:32:42 PM" in date variable.